# heroku node cannot find module 'app/console'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I was adding AWS S3 on my nodejs, this is the first time i use this. 
when i run my app, it had an error

```
2018-10-03T11:56:13.843291+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2018-10-03T11:56:13.827644+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon server.js
2018-10-03T11:56:13.854413+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2018-10-03T11:56:13.854859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2018-10-03T11:56:13.855269+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2018-10-03T11:56:13.855634+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2018-10-03T11:56:13.858988+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! novel-ist-api@1.0.0 start: `nodemon server.js`
2018-10-03T11:56:13.859985+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2018-10-03T11:56:13.860414+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the novel-ist-api@1.0.0 start script.
2018-10-03T11:56:13.859363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2018-10-03T11:56:13.901352+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-03T11:56:13.860881+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem
with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2018-10-03T11:56:13.902089+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-10-03T11_56_13_866Z-debug.log
2018-10-03T11:56:13.901742+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can
be found in:
2018-10-03T11:56:30.126455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=morning-hamlet-21755.herokuapp.com request_id=2db274ec-3b56-4a75-ad11-0fecf2e93821 fwd="180.243.188.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-10-03T11:56:31.865897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=morning-hamlet-21755.herokuapp.com request_id=d54be99d-3257-49c7-ae9a-d3a8ced50d74 fwd="180.243.188.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

then i tried to run `heroku run node console`, it gives me this:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/console'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

i dont know how to fix this

Comment: is `npm start` working?

Comment: can you share file which has code "/app/console" and folder structure

Comment: @AtishayJain yes npm start is working

Comment: @mehta-rohan thats what im confused, theres no "/app/console"  in my code

Comment: do you have nodemon installed?

Comment: @mehta-rohan yes i have in my devdependencies, should i move it to dependencies?

Comment: share your package.json file